# Performance issues of Manipulate with PlotLegends

Tags: manipulate, legending

I always have had performance issues of `Manipulate` while using `PlotLegends`, for example take a look at the following minimal examples

```
man1 = Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate@Table[a*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> 2], {a, -1, 1}];
man2 = Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate@Table[a*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic], {a, -1, 1}];
man3 = Manipulate[
   Grid[{{
      Dynamic@
       Plot[Evaluate@Table[a*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, 
        PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> 350, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97]]
      , LineLegend[Table[ColorData[97][ci], {ci, 1, 8}], Automatic] 
      }}]
   , {a, -1, 1}
   ];
Grid[{{"man1", "man2 (slow)", "man3 (fixed, but cumbersome)"}, {man1, 
   man2, man3}}]
```

[image]

Here, in `man1` a standard plot is manipulated, in `man2` you have the same but only with a legend and in `man3` I used a grid in order to embed the plot with `Dynamic` and the legend separately. `man2` is preeeeeeeeetty slow / not as fluently responsive as `man1`, although the only difference to `man1` is the call of `PlotLegends`. I am using Mathematica 11.0.1 for Windows.

**Is there any way to fix this more elegantly than my grid in `man3` (for larger programs within `Manipulate` this becomes somewhat annoying)?**

Comment: I'm not aware of better workaround, this is what I'm usually doing too.

Comment: @Kuba damn, ok, well I will have to live with it then. Still thx!

Comment: @Kuba Why we don't put a "bug" tag on this post? I think it is a performance bug. I just notice the same thing today...

Comment: @matheorem plot legends just take long to generate, no one said they won't. But yes, it is annoying. From our side it is just a poor quality but if WRI Support confirms that this indeed is worse than it should then bugs can be added. At least that is how I see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea may be to pre-calculate the element that takes time, and then to simply paste it in a ready-to-use form. Of course, if it is acceptable. In your example, if you may have a varying in the course of manipulation number of lines, it is not the way. If, however, the number of lines is always fixed, I would do as follows. First let us prepare the legends:

```
pl = Plot[Evaluate@Table[1*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
        legends = Rasterize[pl[[2, 1]], RasterSize -> 180]
```

[image]

then let us go to manipulate:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@Table[a*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, 
  Epilog -> Inset[legends, Scaled[{0.9, 0.5}]]], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

This might be a way in some cases. I hope it helps.

Have fun!

Comment: Hmmm .... interesting ... one thing I learned indirectly through your solution is that the second part of the plot `pl` (`pl[[2]]`) contains the commands in order to place the legend nicely, i.e., `Placed` and `After`. A combination with your solution would then be `Manipulate[
 Legended[Plot[Evaluate@Table[a*x^n, {n, 1, 8}], {x, 0, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> 2], Placed[legends, After, Identity]], {a, -1, 1}]` so you dont have to rescale within the picture. Thanks!